# Is it possible to rename the emulator in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to give an emulator a name in Android Studio?

In the emulator pull-down box in Android Studio, the emulators created from AVD manager are labelled simply:  "Android SDK built for x86 (mobile)(emulator-nnnn)", where n is an integer.

If you're running multiple emulators, this isn't very helpful. Is there a way to rename each emulator to something more helpful? For example, when I created each emulator, they have names of e.g. "Pixel 4 API 29", and "Nexus 5 API 24" - why aren't these used?

Update: Two screenshots show what I mean. In the top one, the "Nexus 5 API" has been selected; yet it shows as "Android SDK etc". If I select e.g. "Pixel 4 etc", it shows as exactly the same (it actually has an emulator number added that only shows when you open the pull-down).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can edit the name of your AVD.

In the AVD Manager, clic on the pen to the right to edit your configuration and then, you can rename your AVD

[image]

Edit: There names are correctly shown in the pull-down menu, even if launched
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm aware of that; in the AVD window, the emulators show as e.g. "Nexus 5 API" - I've named them as you describe when I created them. But if you start them up, then in the available devices pull-down, they show as e.g. "Android SDK built for x86". However, I also have a real device connected, and this shows as "Pixel 3 XL (mobile)" in the same pull-down box.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the same problem as you can see in my edited answer. I'm using Android Studio 4.1.3

Comment: Hmm, 4.1.3 - so am I. It's a fresh install too - my Windows PC is only about two months old. But my old PC exhibited the same behaviour; when the pull-down is open, the names of the various virtual devices are shown using sensible language. When a virtual device is started, it appears in the upper part of the pulled-down box, with the name "Android SDK...etc". Not a huge problem, but ... sub-optimal :-)

Comment: it renames the name which is displayed when avd is not running

Answer (score 1):

Well what @Bruno said is the easiest way, if it does not work that way you can either try this one, is a little bit tricky though.

In case you use Mac that's an example of how to do it, if you do not use Mac let me know and I'll put the steps to do it on Windows / Linux

Open in Finder

> user.name/.android/avd/

Pd: To be able to show the hidden files press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Find your emulator, in my case I'll show this one :

[image]

Open the `Pixel_4_API_30_-_Android_11.avd` folder (in your case will be different) and open `config.ini` file and change these two params (`AvdId`,`avd.ini.displayname`)

[image]

[image]

And now restart your IDE and it should be updated.

[image]

I'm sure you could change more names, but to ensure the functionality of the emulator, I wouldn't touch too much if you do not know what you are changing.

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I'm on Windows; in my C:\Users\Dee\.android\avd\Pixel_4_API_29.avd file, it starts:  AvdId=Pixel_4_API_29
PlayStore.enabled=true
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Pixel 4 API 29
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8 ... etc
  (sorry about the mangled formatting here, can't do anything about that in "comments") so the sensible names are shown correctly already. I just wish they were used to identify the AVD once it's been started up :-)

Comment: Have you solved this? If so feel free to upvote + mark this question as a correct to let other users know this may help! Thanks

Comment: TLDR: No, sorry, it didn't work. Primarily I use a Proper Computer, I also have a dirty Mac. On both of them, I've looked at the config.ini file - they both have the AvdId and avd.ini.displayname set to the descriptive string. In Android Studio, on both Windows and dirtyMac, the list of AVDs available shows e.g. "Android SDK built for x86". So, it's consistant across platforms. However, on the Mac, any iOS emulators I have running do show the name string I assigned to it. Note that if you look at the screen captures at the top, it does show the AVD names in the lower "Open xxx" section. Hmmm

Comment: it renames the name which is displayed when avd is not running

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the device name "emulator-nnnn" from Android Studio as that name belongs to the device. This is the name that you see in "adb devices" output.

For a real device, you have to change its name by opening the Settings app from the device.

For an emulator, in theory you can do the same, you open the Settings app inside the emulator when emulator is running. But I haven't tested this because my emulator is very slow.